# Bigram\n gram words\prases list for NLP of reviews

Tags: nlp

I am doing an NLP project with N-Grams splitting of sentences at the word level.
Ie; President of the united states ; must be recognized as a noun.
But using POS Tagger, I get:

> This_DT president_NN of_IN the_DT united_JJ states_NNS looks_VBZ
>   awesome_JJ

Any file links or suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: What part-of-speech tagger are you using currently?

Comment: You will need some sort of Named Entity recognizer either "manual" or with machine learning technique (such as CRF)

Comment: Stanford POS. Could you please tell me more about machine learning techniques.